# Evaluate value with parantheses in NSExpression

Tags: ios, swift, nsexpression

I have to evaluate the following value in NSExpression.Please help me.

```
let calculateExpression = NSExpression(format: "6(9*9)")
    if let calculateConvertedValue = calculateExpression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber {
         outputValue = calculateConvertedValue.stringValue
        print("Output",outputValue)

    }
```

Comment: Simple answer: You can't. NSExpression is pretty limited in its syntax. Use a proper math parser, for example https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser.

Comment: @MartinR How to use DDMathParser. Can you give me the sample?